# xml serialize with many element with same name and different type and namespace. How can i serialize the xml using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization, soap, xml-deserialization

I getting soap response in xml file and i want to serialize the xml into model. the problem is the xml have many elements with same name and different type and namespace.
I getting xml file as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf 8" ?> 
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
  <trialCreditVendResp xmlns="http://www.sample.co.za/xmlvend/revenue/2.1/schema">
   <creditVendReceipt>
  <transactions>
  <tx xsi:type="CreditVendTx">
  <amt value="22291.43" /> 
  <creditTokenIssue xmlns:q1="http://www.sample.co.za/xmlvend/base/2.1/schema" xsi:type="q1:SaleCredTokenIssue">
  <q1:units value="22291.5" siUnit="KWh" /> 
  <q1:resource xsi:type="q1:Elec" /> 
  </creditTokenIssue>
  </tx>
  <tx xsi:type="ServiceChrgTx">
  <amt value="10.00" symbol="R" /> 
  <accDesc>Fixed Fee</accDesc> 
  <accNo>DEMO3</accNo> 
  </tx>
  <tx xsi:type="ServiceChrgTx">
  <amt value="20.00" symbol="R" /> 
  <accDesc>Service Charge</accDesc> 
  <accNo>DEMO3</accNo> 
  </tx>
  <tx xsi:type="ServiceChrgTx">
  <amt value="2678.57" symbol="R" /> 
  <accDesc>VAT</accDesc> 
  <accNo>DEMO3</accNo> 
  </tx>
  <tenderAmt value="25000" /> 
  <change value="0" /> 
  </transactions>
  </creditVendReceipt>
  </trialCreditVendResp>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann't have several types with same name in one namespace. To make some .NET (C#, VB...) classes and generate proxy class you can use wsdl.exe util from .net. The wsdl information on http://youservice.com/service.asmx?wsdl

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx